# Why drop the argument in the differential? $dx$ vs $dx(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a simple ODE ($m$ is a constant):
$$ \frac{dx}{dy}=m \tag{1}$$ 
So $dx=m\,dy \quad \Longrightarrow x=my+C$.

**But** isn't $x$ a function of $y$? Can we write the ODE *explicit* as
$$
\frac{dx(y)}{dy}=m \tag{2}
$$
$$
dx(y)=m\, dy
$$
$$
\int dx(y)=\int m\, dy \quad \Longrightarrow x(y)=my+C \quad?
$$
Is this explicit form correct? My book doesn't justify why the argument of $dx$ and $x$ is dropped in $(1)$.

Comment: It's the same thing. The only difference is in notation.

Comment: If you really want to make it clear that some variable is dependent, or a function, of another variable then yeah, use the argument notation. But for $x$ and $y$, it's normally taken as given that they're dependent.